# unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'RegexURLPattern' and 'str'

Tags: python, django, django-urls

Hi I am having trouble resolving this,

I followed http://blackglasses.me/2013/09/17/custom-django-user-model/
tutorial.

I can't recall but I think I read somewhere that if you use functional views you must import something but not sure if that is the case here or if this is true.

Here is my code for urls.py in the accounts app

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from accounts import views

urlpatterns = patterns(
   url(r'^register$', 'accounts.views.register', name='register'),
   url(r'^login$', 'accounts.views.login', name='login'),
   url(r'^logout$', 'accounts.views.logout', name='logout'),
```

)

in the main urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = ['',
    url(r'^accounts/', include('accounts.urls', namespace='accounts')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
  ]
```

Below is the error message and traceback

```
Environment:
Django Version: 1.8.5
Python Version: 3.4.0

Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8777/

Django Version: 1.8.5
Python Version: 3.4.0


Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8777/
Django Version: 1.8.5
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'RegexURLPattern' and 'str'
Exception Location: /home/kevin/djangoP/envRU/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py in add_prefix, line 223
Python Executable:  /home/kevin/djangoP/envRU/bin/python
Python Version: 3.4.0


Traceback:

    File "/home/kevin/djangoP/envRU/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
      119.                 resolver_match = resolver.resolve(request.path_info)

    File "/home/kevin/djangoP/envRU/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
      365.             for pattern in self.url_patterns:


    File "/home/kevin/djangoP/envRU/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in url_patterns
      401.         patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)

    File "/home/kevin/djangoP/envRU/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in urlconf_module
      395.             self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)

    File "/home/kevin/djangoP/envRU/lib/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py" in import_module
      109.     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)

    File "/home/kevin/djangoP/ru/rulinked/rulinked/urls.py" in <module>
      20.     url(r'^accounts/', include('accounts.urls', namespace='accounts')),


    File "/home/kevin/djangoP/envRU/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/conf/urls/__init__.py" in include
      33.         urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)


    File "/home/kevin/djangoP/envRU/lib/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py" in import_module
      109.     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)


    File "/home/kevin/djangoP/ru/rulinked/accounts/urls.py" in <module>
      7.     url(r'^logout$', 'accounts.views.logout', name='logout'),

    File "/home/kevin/djangoP/envRU/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/conf/urls/__init__.py" in patterns
      61.             t.add_prefix(prefix)

    File "/home/kevin/djangoP/envRU/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in add_prefix
      223.         self._callback_str = prefix + '.' + self._callback_str

    Exception Type: TypeError at /
    Exception Value: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'RegexURLPattern' and 'str'
```

If you read that far then thank you, I know its alot but I am really lost and didn’t know where else to get help.

Comment: Try `views.register` instead of  `accounts.views.register`, same for rest two and let me know if it works

Comment: @red8alice does it work if you chage your urlpatterns to this: "urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^accounts/', include('accounts.urls', namespace='accounts')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
  ]" (I removed the empty string in the urlpatterns)

Comment: Hi MohitC I did change it and this has helped in conjunction with knbk advice. Thank you for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're confusing the two available syntaxes.

The `patterns()` function takes a prefix as the first argument, which is a (possibly empty) string, and returns a list with the prefix added to each pattern. The other arguments are `url()` instances. A plain list should only contain `url()` instances, and you can't add a common prefix.

`patterns()` is deprecated, so it's better to use a list everywhere:

accounts/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
   url(r'^register$', 'accounts.views.register', name='register'),
   url(r'^login$', 'accounts.views.login', name='login'),
   url(r'^logout$', 'accounts.views.logout', name='logout'),
]
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^accounts/', include('accounts.urls', namespace='accounts')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
]
```

As for importing views: you need to import them if you pass the function itself. If you don't  import it first, the function is not available and results in a `NameError`. Right now you're passing an import path, not the function, so you don't have to import anything. This is deprecated as well (for views, not for including other url configurations), so for compatibility with future Django versions you can change it to this:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from accounts import views

urlpatterns = [
   url(r'^register$', views.register, name='register'),
   url(r'^login$', views.login, name='login'),
   url(r'^logout$', views.logout, name='logout'),
]
```

Note that the second argument to `url()` is no longer a string, but the view function itself in the imported `views` module.

Comment: thank you knbk this seems to have done the trick, and thank you for every one who contributed. just as a note , should I not use a views import and structure as I have done  as it will be depreciated? thank again

Answer (score 0):

Edit your app urls.py to this:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from accounts import views

urlpatterns = patterns('', // add the empty string here
   url(r'^register$', 'accounts.views.register', name='register'),
   url(r'^login$', 'accounts.views.login', name='login'),
   url(r'^logout$', 'accounts.views.logout', name='logout'),
)
```

Also, remove the empty string from your main urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^accounts/', include('accounts.urls', namespace='accounts')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
  ]
```

because I donèt think it is needed when using the square brackets version.